# Verb for "would like"

Tags: translation, word-choice

I've been using a learning app and this sentence came up, **Willst du ins Kino gehen?** and the translation is **Would you like to go to the cinema?**.

For all other times *möchte* has been used for *would like.* Is *willst* correct in this example?

Comment: Related: [Möchten and wollen explanation](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/28549/9551) and [What’s the difference between “möchte”, “will”, “lieber”, “würde”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/10939/9551)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would translate "Willst du ins Kino gehen?" with "Do you want to go to the cinema". According to opinion the suggested translation with "Would you ..." isn't correct.

Comment: This is simply not correct. You can also translate it with "Would you like to ...". Have a look at Jan's answer.

Answer (score 13):

In most cases, the forms *möchtest du*, *magst du*, *willst du* can be used interchangeably without changing the meaning.

The difference is style. Many parents attempt to teach their children to use *möchte* rather than *will* because it is more polite especially if the subject is *I*:

> Ich *will* ins Kino gehen.
>
> Ich *möchte* ins Kino gehen.

You can compare this to ‘I want to go to the cinema’ and ‘I would like to go to the cinema.’ *Mögen* in its indicative mood is somewhere in-between but has fallen out of use for this time of expression; rather, it is now used to express enjoyment.

For completeness: *möchte* is not a verb by itself but the conjunctive II form of *mögen*.

Answer (score 1):

The literal translation of

> **Would you like** to do something?
>   **Would you like** to sleep?
>   **Would you like** to go to the cinema?

is

> **Würdest du es mögen**, etwas zu tun?
>   **Würdest du es mögen**, zu schlafen?
>   **Würdest du es mögen**, ins Kino zu gehen?

But the phrase »würdest du es mögen« is no good style. It is grammatically correct, but it is bumpy and awkward German.

A better phrase with the same meaning, but of a much smoother style is »möchtest du«:

> **Möchtest du** etwas tun?
>   **Möchtest du** schlafen?
>   **Möchtest du** ins Kino gehen?

(As you can see, now there is no »zu« before the infinitive!)

The verb »möchten« has a synonym, which is »wollen«. Both tranlate into the english verb »to want«.
See [https://translate.google.at/?hl=de&tab=wT#de/en/Ich%20möchte%20gehen](https://translate.google.at/?hl=de&tab=wT#de/en/Ich%20m%C3%B6chte%20gehen).
and https://translate.google.at/?hl=de&tab=wT#de/en/Ich%20will%20gehen.

So you also can say:

> **Willst du** etwas tun?
>   **Willst du** schlafen?
>   **Willst du** ins Kino gehen?

Be aware, that »Ich will« does **not** translate into »I will«! It is »I want to«! (see also https://german.stackexchange.com/a/25474/1487)

Comment: Except of course that there is no verb “möchten”.

Comment: @CarstenS: Von welchem Wort ist dann hier die Rede?: http://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-möchten.html

Comment: Das Verb ist *mögen* und *möchte* ist der Konjunktiv II.

Comment: @Jan und CarstenS: Das würde bedeuten, dass »Ich möchte Milch« der Konjunktiv II (auch »Irrealis« genannt) von »Ich mag Milch« wäre. »Ich möchte Milch« würde also den unwahrscheinlichen Fall beschreiben, dass ich Milch mögen würde. Tatsächlich drückt »Ich möchte Milch« aber aus, dass ich ich ein Verlangen nach Milch habe. Das ist nicht wirklich dasselbe.

Comment: @Hubert … doch …? Vergleiche »Was willst du?«, »Was magst du?«, und »Was möchtest du?« Alle drei können *kontextabhängig* das Gleiche bedeuten: »Welches Produkt darf ich dir reichen?«

Comment: @CarstenS und Jan: Ich räume gerne in, dass »möchten« aus dem Konjunktiv II von »mögen« entstanden sein könnte, aber im wirklichen Leben wird dieses Verb nicht so verwendet. »Möchten« wird wie ein eigenständiges Verb verwendet, mit einer Bedeutung, die mit dem Konjunktiv von *mögen* nichts mehr zu tun hat.

Comment: @Jan: »Ich mag Milch« bedeutet: Ich finde Milch sympathisch/wohlschmeckend/begehrenswert usw. Der Satz drück also aus, dass ich zu Milch eine positive und wohlwollende Einstellung habe. Der Satz drückt nicht zwingend aus, dass ich jetzt gerade den Wunsch habe, Milch zu trinken, zu besitzen, mich damit zu übergießen oder was auch immer. (Diese Interpretation ist zwar zulässig, aber eben nicht die einzig mögliche). Hingegen sagt »Ich möchte Milch« aus, dass ich jetzt den Wunsch habe, in den Besitz von Milch zu gelangen, um mit ihr meine Bedürfnisse zu befriedigen. ...

Comment: Fortsetzung: ...  Der Satz sagt nur wenig über meine allgemeine Einstellung zu Milch aus.

Comment: In Deutschland kann »Ich mag (eine) Milch« auch heißen, dass ich jetzt gerne eine haben möchte. Anscheinend ist diese Bedeutung in Österreich verlorengegangen …

Comment: Hubert, das ist teils richtig, nur dass dieses Verb immer noch keinen richtigen Infinitiv hat. (* Es genügt nicht, etwas zu möchten.) Die Information, dass *möchte* ein Konjunktiv II ist, einem Anfänger gegenüber zu unterschlagen, finde ich deshalb nicht unbedingt falsch. Aber mit *würde mögen* zu beginnen und dann nicht zu erwähnen, dass der Konjunktiv II von *möge* gerade *möchte* ist, und stattdessen von dem anderen Verb * *möchten* zu erzählen, fand ich dann doch ungeschickt. Daher mein freundlicher Hinweis. Deine Antwort, es stehe aber so irgendwo im Internet...

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich stimme dir vollkommen zu, dass *möchte* und ähnliche Formen wie ein eigenständiges Verb verwendet werden, und eine Initiative, *möchten* als eigenständigen Infinitiv zu verankern, würde ich voll unterstützen. Nur läuft die Argumentation, dass man über den "unwahrscheinlichen Fall" spricht, meiner Meinung nach ins Leere, da eine ähnliche Konstruktion in Form von "hätte gern" ebenso gebräuchlich ist und sich dort der Gebrauch des Konjunktivs II kaum abstreiten lässt.

Comment: Achso … »Wenn ich Milch nicht möchte, tränke ich sie nicht.« Aber wer verwendet heutzutage schon Konjunktive, außer der sehr begrenzten Liste, die ich irgendwo hier mal zusammengestellt habe.

Comment: @Jan: Nein, das ist in Österreich genau so. Wichtig ist das Wort »auch«, das du ganz zurecht gebraucht hast. Wenn ich sage »Ich möchte Milch« kann man dieses »auch« getrost weglassen, weil dann nur die von dir gemeinte Interpretation möglich ist. »Ich möchte Milch« kann nicht als »Ich finde Milch zwar toll, will jetzt gerade aber keine haben« interpretiert werden. Bei »Ich mag Milch« ist diese Interpretation aber möglich.

Comment: @CarstenS: Rekrut zum Offizier: »Ich möchte aber nicht stramm stehen.« Dessen Antwort: »Was fällt Ihnen ein? Sie haben hier nichts zu **möchten**! Sie führen Befehle aus!« In welcher Form wird das fett hervorgehobene »möchten« hier verwendet? Ist das kein Infinitiv? Ich weiß, dass dieser Infinitiv (noch) nicht im Duden steht. Aber: Es *ist* ein Infinitiv, und er wird in der Umgangssprache immer öfter verwendet.

Comment: Sicher gibt es Leute, die das sagen, aber es ist (noch) nicht standardsprachlich, und ich denke, dass das viele Sprecher auch als zumindest schief empfinden, selbst wenn ihnen der Grund nicht klar sein sollte.

Comment: In meinen Ohren müsste der Offizier zurückbrüllen: »Sie haben hier nichts zu **mögen!**«

Comment: @Jan: Der Rekrut hat aber eben *nicht* gesagt: »Ich *mag* nicht stramm stehen«, sondern »Ich *möchte* nicht stramm stehen«. Auch wenn die Bedeutungen von »ich mag« und »ich möchte« nahe beieinander liegen, so sind sie eben doch nicht genau gleich (siehe oben). Daher ist »Sie haben nichts zu *mögen*« semantisch nicht korrekt. »Sie haben nichts zu *mögen*« bedeutet: »Sie haben nichts gut zu finden«. Aber »Sie haben nichts zu *möchten*« bedeutet: »Sie haben keine Wünsche zu haben«. Es ist nämlich so, dass der Rekrut gerne etwas gut oder schlecht finden darf. Er darf aber keine Wünsche haben.

Comment: Wir drehen uns im Kreis, aber da *möchte* zu *mögen* die Konjunktivform ist … Ist es egal, ob eine Teilbedeutung im Konjuntiv häufiger anzutreffen ist als im Indikativ, das Verb ist (meines Erachtens) dasselbe.

Comment: Lustigerweise ist es ja im Englischen dasselbe: "I would like to go to the cinema" soll ja überlicherweise auch nicht "ins Kino zu gehen fände ich unter Umständen toll, aber ich will jetzt gerade nicht" aussagen. Bei "would like" sieht man halt nur den Infinitiv noch deutlicher als im deutschen Äquivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Additional proposal (a little closer to the original  than *willst du* in my opinion):

> Hast Du Lust, ins Kino zu gehen?

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: @CarstenS: It at least answers, what is given in the title. I admit, that the text itself is somewhat blurry in that respect.

Comment: I find “is *willst* correct” clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Technically both are correct. "Willst du ins Kino", can be translated as 'Would you like to go to the cinema', in terms of meaning/understanding only though.
The sentences use different registers (form/informal).

You can use 'Willst du ins Kino?' with friends and those you know well - it's more along the lines of '(Do you) fancy going to the cinema?'

'Would you like to go to the cinema' is more formal.

The use of 'möchten' is different in different German speaking areas. I.e. IN Austrian German 'Magst du Cola?', can mean 'Do you want some coke', rather than 'Do you like coke?'

Comment: Note that technically there is no infinitive "möchten".